# Adjective clauses: "in order to" or "and"

Tags: relative-clauses

Can we use adjective clauses this way like below?

> This is a subject **that I did some research and figured out.**
>
> This is a word **that I read a book and learned.**
>
> This is a method **that I did a lot of experiments and came up with.**
>
> This is a car **that I sold my old stuff in order to buy.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **and** and **in order to** in sentences that include relative clauses but not in the way that you have done.

This is the glue that sticks plastic and [that] is waterproof.

He is the man that took my car in order to drive to town.

Unfortunately, all of your sentences have fatal mistakes.

"And" is a coordinating conjunction and joins two clauses of equal value.

"In order to" introduces a subordinate adverbial clause of purpose

This is a subject that I did some research **on** and **then/eventually** [that I] figured out. (There are two subordinate clauses here.)

This is a word that I read **in** a book and **then** [that I] learned.  (There are two relative (subordinate adjectival) clauses here.)

This is a method that ***I came up with*** **by doing** a lot of experiments. (**by doing** a lot of experiments is an adverbial phrase.

This is **the** car that I **bought** from the proceeds of selling my old stuff.